# Truble with subversion. Can't cleanup "Log command is mislocated"

Tags: mac, svn, xcode

I am working with Xcode and subversion on the Mac, but my files have become messy and Xcode and subversion are complaining. When I run `svn commit` or `update` I get the message

```
svn: Working copy '.' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

but when I run `svn cleanup` I get the message

```
svn: In directory '.'
svn: Error processing command 'committed' in '.'
svn: Log command for directory 'buttNew2~iPad.png' is mislocated
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Delete the directory and execute the 'svn up' command in the parent directory.

Comment: Thanks, helped me. The problem was that I did case-sensitive rename on Mac OS, and SVN failed to understand what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

svn always messes up in several different ways. The quick fix is always to do a clean checkout and copy any modifications you have in the broken checkout, manually.

And then switch to git.
Actually, just switch to git ;)
There are several handy commandline tools for importing your svn repo to git, preserving your history.

Comment: Because my SVN folders where messy I could not do a checkout, but I copied everything and removed all .svn subfolders. Now, Xcode works fine. I will try GIT later, right now I'am to busy programming... +1 anyway.